# How can I create "friendmoji's" - dual Bitmoji images with 2 people in the same image?

Tags: facebook-messenger, emoji

The Bitmoji platform now supports "Friendmoji's" – the ability to show 2 people within the same image.

Here's an example:

[image]

What are the various ways I can generate these images?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to create Bitmoji's, although only a few of them appear to support *Friendmoji's* to date (and they are not well-documented).

Both users will likely need to have created a Bitmoji account and setup their avatar for this to work. That is, you cannot create a custom *Friendmoji* without setting up a Bitmoji account for the other person.

#### These apps appear to support *Friendmoji's*:

- Snapchat mobile apps
- Bitmoji for Facebook Messenger
- Bitmoji for Slack

#### These other methods don't appear to support *Friendmoji's* as yet:

- Bitmoji iOS app
- Bitmoji iOS custom keyboard
- Bitmoji Chrome extension
- Bitmoji website

If you know of any updates to this list, please post in the comments.

### In Slack

Once you've added the Bitmoji app to Slack, you can simply type:

```
/bitmoji @[username] [search_term]
```

Here is a list of keywords that can be used for Friendmoji's:

`achoo`
`alarm clock`
`are you kidding me`
`avocado`
`ayyy lmao`
`backpack`
`bacon`
`bad ass`
`bath`
`beach`
`bedtime`
`besties`
`blue heart`
`blushin`
`bruh`
`brutal`
`burger`
`can i help you`
`can't deal`
`car`
`challenge accepted`
`champagne`
`cheerio`
`cheerio`
`cheers`
`chill`
`chinese new year`
`cocktail`
`coffee`
`cuddles`
`cuddles`
`cup of tea`
`current mood`
`dab`
`daisy`
`dead`
`do it`
`don't play`
`dope`
`drink`
`dry`
`egg`
`facepalm`
`fail`
`fake news`
`food`
`fu`
`funnel`
`giddy up`
`giggle`
`go me`
`go you`
`good call`
`good morning`
`good night`
`grass`
`gtfo`
`guitar`
`happy`
`happy valentine's day`
`hate myself`
`heart balloons`
`heh`
`hello`
`hey`
`hi you`
`high five`
`hmph`
`hole`
`hot`
`hot dog`
`hubba hubba`
`i forgot`
`i hate you`
`i hear ya`
`i like`
`i love you`
`i love you dummy`
`i woke up like this`
`ice`
`ice cream`
`jump`
`karaoke`
`kiss`
`knock knock`
`L`
`let's party`
`life is hard`
`limo`
`lit`
`lol wat`
`love`
`lute`
`marry me`
`math`
`miss you`
`miss you`
`nah fam`
`new year new me`
`no way`
`nope`
`not today`
`one love`
`onion`
`oopsie woopsie`
`party`
`peas in a pod`
`petty af`
`photo`
`rain`
`rainbow`
`regrets`
`salt shaker`
`santa's lap`
`saturday`
`saxophone`
`shame`
`sick`
`sleepy`
`sloth`
`smooch`
`snowman`
`so extra`
`spit take`
`spooky`
`stay tuned`
`sub`
`sunny`
`surfing`
`sweet`
`team awesome`
`tennis`
`thank you`
`thanks`
`that sucks`
`that's cold`
`thinking about you`
`tired`
`tree`
`tuesday`
`tumbleweed`
`turn up`
`u get me`
`uh huh`
`uh oh`
`watermelon`
`we got this`
`what up fam`
`why me`
`woe is me`
`woke`
`woke`
`woohoo`
`xmas`
`y tho`
`you bet`
`you can do it`
`you got it`
`you guys suck`
`you had one job`
`you're the best`
`zero chill`

Thank you to:

- https://medium.com/kevins-daily-makers-academy-blog/list-of-bitmoji-search-terms-in-slack-d29dcfa20a83
- https://github.com/luoser/bitmoji-slack-commands

Answer (score 0):

My Dual Bitmoji technique (iOS)

Prelude: You need Snapchat (SC) and Bitmoji apps, with your own Bitmoji created, then linked to SC. The picture you wish to photobomb must be in your camera roll. You must “friend” the other person whose Bitmoji you wish to team with.

1. Tap on your SC Bitmoji (upper left corner)
2. Tap My Friends
3. Scroll to the Bitmoji avatar of the person you want.
4. Tap and hold the Bitmoji of the person you want, until the pop-up appears.
5. Tap the chat icon, outlined in blue.
6. Tap the framed picture icon on the left side of the screen.
7. Scroll and tap the picture to be used from camera roll.
8. Tap edit at the bottom.
9. Tap the stickers icon, it looks like a post-it note.
10. You should now have over 300 double Bitmoji to choose from, divided among 6 menu icons at the bottom (horizontal scroll).
11. Tap the selected Bitmoji, placing it onto the picture.
12. Resize, rotate, and position the Bitmoji as needed. (Add other SC edits if you wish, like text, other stickers, etc.)
13. Tap the Save icon! It should now say Saved! and a check mark should appear.
14. Tap the X in the upper left corner to cancel the chat (if you don't want to send the picture now).
15. Tap the blue arrow in the upper right corner to exit to chat screen.
16. Swipe right to return to SC home screen.
    The new picture should be in your camera roll, to use as you wish.

[image]